# *Gödel, Escher, Bach* quote illustrating syntax vs. semantics?

Tags: semantics, hofstadter

On what page of Hofstadter's *Gödel, Escher, Bach* (*GEB*) is the paragraph he quotes which is syntactically correct but almost completely void of any meaning except for a very esoteric group of specialists? Hofstadter used it to illustrate the importance of context in meaning, as well as the difference between syntax and semantics.

Comment: There is another phrase which I learned in linguistics class to illustrate this distinction: "More people have been to Paris than I have".

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: ☺ Hofstadter's example was paragraph length, though, and I think it might've been just one sentence. I wish I could find it; it's been since about year 2000 since I read *GEB*. thanks for the help

Comment: According to this link, there is a section starting on page 630 dealing with Syntax and Semantics : http://www.egodeath.com/geb.htm